# How to set positions in an array of specific component with its selector using Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, components

I'm very new to Angular and I would like to know if it is possible to set positions of an array, that is already declared as empty in one component, with its selector in another component.

For example, lets say I have component named "array" and in the array.component.ts file I'm declaring and empty array:

```
export class ArrayComponent {

array: number[] = [];

}
```

In my main "app" component I would like to use the "array" component and set its values with its selector:

app.component.html:

```
<app-array array="10"></app-array>
```

Is this possible? And if yes, how should I implement it? Should I use Attribute directives or?

Thanks in advance.

I didn't tried any solutions, because I'm not sure how to implement it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@Input()` decorator to pass information from a parent component to a child component

`array.component.ts`

```
export class ArrayComponent {
  @Input() array: number[] = [];
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<app-array [array]="[10]"></app-array>
```

*Note: This will pass an array of value `[10]` into the `array` variable*

---

To instead generate an array of length 10, you could build your array in your parent component and pass this to your child. For example:

`array.component.ts`

```
export class ArrayComponent {
  @Input() array: number[] = [];
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<app-array [array]="parentArray"></app-array>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  parentArray: number[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentArray = this.buildArrayOfNumbers(10)
  }

  buildArrayOfNumbers(length: number): number {
    return Array.from({length}, (_, i) => i + 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however that is not exactly what I would like to achieve. I guess I didn't explain it properly. I would like to set 10 values in the array and I would expect it to be: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], because I would like to loop through them and display them after.

Comment: Not a problem, and I thought that would be the case. You will not be able to achieve that with the syntax you have used as building your array will require JavaScript somewhere. You will need to either 1) create the array in the parent component and pass it into your child component or 2) pass the configuration (e.g. the number `10`) into the child and then have the child component contain the logic which can take the configuration and turn that into an array

Comment: I have added an example for scenario 1 which generates an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` as soon as `AppComponent` loads. This array then gets passed into `ArrayComponent` for use. Hope this helps!